# Delete selected item from TextCell Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making a simple CRUD function in my Xamarin.Forms app, but I can't understand how to delete from the list.

**My question** is this, how do I delete the selected item in the TextCell? As of now since I am using `var delete = _saveData[0];` I'm obviously deleting the first item. My guess is that I have to get the Id and pass it to the `OnDelete` but I have no idea how.

Maybe there is a much better approach to this? It doesn't have to be a TextCell as long as I can present the data as

```
Name
Status
```

and then be able to e.g longpress on the cell and choose to delete it.

**My xaml page:**

*StatusPage.xaml*

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyCRUDApp.StatusPage"
             Title="Status"
             Icon="ic_info.png">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Choose status:"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Firstname Lastname" x:Name="Name"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Available/Busy" x:Name="Status"/>
            <Button Text="Add" Clicked="OnAdd"/>

            <Label Text="Statuses:" VerticalOptions="End"/>
            <ListView VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" x:Name="mylistview">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                 Detail="{Binding Status}" 
                                 Tapped="OnDelete"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**The relevant parts of the code-behind:**

*StatusPage.xaml.cs*

```
namespace MyCRUDApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StatusPage : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
        private ObservableCollection<SaveData> _saveData;

        public StatusPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<SaveData>();
            var abc = await _connection.Table<SaveData>().ToListAsync();
            _saveData = new ObservableCollection<SaveData>(abc);
            mylistview.ItemsSource = _saveData;  
        }

        void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var SaveData = new SaveData { Name = Name.Text, Status = Status.Text };
            _connection.InsertAsync(SaveData);
            _saveData.Add(SaveData);
        }

        void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var delete = _saveData[0];
            _connection.DeleteAsync(delete);
            _saveData.Remove(delete);
        }
    }
}
```

**My SaveData class**

*SaveData.cs*

```
namespace MyCRUDApp.Models
{
    public class SaveData
    {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to trigger the event
add event ItemTapped  to the listView

```
<ListView x:Name="ObjectList"
                      **ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"**
                      HasUnevenRows="True">
```

event implementation looks like

```
 public void OnItemTapped ( object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e ) {
            var item = e.Item as Object;
            //here you can call the delete function
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good way of doing it as well. But the problem here is to delete the selected item, since it obviously only will delete the first in the list when I'm using `_saveData[0]`.

Comment: Well, after a needed break I gave it a shot again and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, add a public property to store the currently selected item to your code:

```
public SaveData SelectedSaveData{get; set;} // Add appropriate handling, e.g. INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then bind this to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`, remove the `Tapped` binding on your `TextCell` and bind to `ItemSelected` on the `ListView` instead.

```
<ListView VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
          x:Name="mylistview" 
          ItemSelected="OnDelete"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaveData, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Detail="{Binding Status}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Now `SelectedSaveData` will always hold the one that was selected in the `ListView` and can be used in your methods, e.g.

```
void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connection.DeleteAsync(SelectedSaveData);
    _saveData.Remove(SelectedSaveData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand how it should work, except for the property. Should I add something like `OnPropertyChanged` to the `setter` or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: No, you don't have to to make the delete functionality work, but you may want to if you're doing other things that need the UI to update if the `SelectedSaveData` property changes.

Comment: There is something I am missing, because the SelectedSaveData is always null when running the app.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice how you were calling `OnDelete`. Edited my answer to clarify. Deleting an item with just a tap is dangerous, though.

Comment: Yeah I will absolutely change it later, at this stage I just wanna get it to work. Unfortunately I still can't get it to work, the `SelectedSaveData` is still null. I don't understand what I am missing...

Comment: Expand the getter and setter of your property and set a breakpoint on the setter. Check if that gets hit at all, and if so, before or after OnDelete? If there's no hit at all, you most likely have a problem with your binding syntax.

Comment: The setter is never getting a hit. Maybe it is a problem with the binding then. I have re-checked it so many times without finding anything. If I change back the code to the `_saveData[0]` it still deletes the first item so the binding is functional in that aspect at least.